# unresolved reference get_func() in pycharm

Tags: python, function

I am sorry but i am just starting with python, but i had a Unresolved reference get_func() error in the following code:

```
class Foo:

     fo = open(file_name, "r")

     with open(file_name, 'r') as file:

         examples = int(file.readline())
         attributes = int(file.readline())

         name_of_attributes = [n for n in (file.readline().replace(" ", "")).split(",")]

        all_examples = file.readlines()



    get_func(); // error here

    def get_func(self):
        list_of_keys = ['S_Length', 'S_Width', 'P_Length', 'P_Width', 'Predicate']
        with open('example.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                return;
```

Comment: It IS an unresolved reference in this scope. Name `get_func` does not exists there. I'll suggest reading basic Python tutorial, since this code exhibits some fundamental mistakes and answering this question as defined now is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point where you're invoking the function, Python hasn't yet encountered its definition, so it doesn't yet know to what you're referring. In C/C++ (judging from your in-code comment), there's a clear distinction between compiling the code and then running it. In Python, the interpreter conceptually just interprets it as it goes along (there's bytecode compilation, but that's besides the point).

Try changing the order so that the invocation is after the definition:

```
 def get_func(self): # first define
     ...

 get_func() # now invoke it
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a class method you should use the `self` attribute you have set in the method `get_func` declaration, like this `self.get_func()`. You can abandon the colon at the end.

I think you should be reading more about classes in Python, check out this Wikibook article - [Python beginner's tutorial to classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes)